# Shifting a merged cell down

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I am writing a VBA script that will shift a merged cell down.  When it does this a pop-up box comes up warning the user that this operation will unmerge merged cells.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A28")) Is Nothing Then
    Range("c28").Insert Shift:=xlDown
End If
```

I would like one of two things to happen.

A. Always automatically accept Yes so the popup doesn't show to the user. (and I'll re-merge in VBA after the insert)

B. Is there a way to shift down without unmerging to begin with.

Comment: Have you merged **A28** thru **C28**??

Comment: for case "A" you could use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` in the beggining of the sub and `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` in the very end

Comment: C28:D28 is the merged cell that is shifting down on the double click.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @Josh, have you tried to use `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` as in my comment above?

Comment: @Josh, btw, what are you going to shift? only cells in column `C` or entire row?

Comment: @simoco, it's actually going to shift B28:I28.  As it shifts down, the new row that was inserted does not have the merged cells that were there before.  Is that impossible to solve without just manually merging again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments this should work and avoid the warning:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A28")) Is Nothing Then
        Range("c28:d28").Insert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
End Sub
```

If you still get the warning, try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A28")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Range("c28:d28").Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried that, it did not work.  The warning came up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a situation where you don't know exactly which cells are merged, you can use the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A28")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Me.Range("c28").MergeArea.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
```

But be aware that merged areas below row 28 can also be unmerged by this action. For example if say cells B30:F30 are merged the code above will cause them to unmerge.